# How to fullscreen GTK# window when app starts as xsession?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gtk, ubuntu-14.04

I wrote simple GTK-based application with C#/Mono stack on Linux(Ubuntu 14.04) and confront with a trouble!
When i debug my app under GNOME sessions Window.Fullscreen() works fine, but if i login into selfcreated xsession where my app start without desktop environment this method dont want to work properly, window size equals to default height\width defined in constructor.

Screenshot: [image]

My .desktop look like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Kiosk
Comment=Kiosk
Exec=mono /home/user/Desktop/NES/NES/bin/Debug/NES.exe
Icon=
Type=Application
```

and C# code for opening window look like this

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow ();
window.Fullscreen ();
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with PyGtk!
I' trying to make a USBlive. The command start with startx and it works fine but...it isn't fullscreen. Both window.fullscreen() and window.maximize() don't work.
Tried on my environment (kubuntu) everything it's fine.

Comment: i found a makeshift solution: set defaultHeight and defaultWidth properties before show window and then use Show() or Fullscreen() method, its work fine for me :)

Comment: i was just about to write the same thing XD